# Erlang: strange output formatting

Tags: xml, file, formatting, erlang, output

Windows 7 x64, Erlang-OTP 17.
I wrote simple module like this:

```
-module (somequery).
-export ([fbquery/2]).

fbquery(P1,P2) ->  
    inets:start(),
    ssl:start(),
    token = "78a8shd67tyajsndweiu03hr83h19j",
    Encoded = {"Authorization","Basic " ++ base64:encode_to_string(lists:append([token,":",""]))},
    ContentType = "application/xml",
    Headers = [Encoded, {"Content-Type",ContentType}],
    Options = [{body_format,binary}],
    {ok, File}=file:read_file(P1),
    Res = httpc:request(post, {"https://datapi.com/api/xml4-8", Headers, ContentType, File}, [], Options),
    file:write_file(P2, io_lib:fwrite("~p.\n", [Res])).
```

It works both in interactive and complied, and Res term showing data

```
59> Res.                                                                                                     
{ok,{{"HTTP/1.1",200,"OK"},
     [{"connection","keep-alive"},
      {"date","Tue, 05 May 2015 10:58:53 GMT"},
      {"server","nginx"},
      {"vary","Accept-Encoding"},
      {"content-length","5508"},
      {"content-type","application/xml; charset=utf-8"},
      {"x-frame-options","SAMEORIGIN"},
      {"p3p",
       "CP=\"To see our privacy policy, go here: http://www.datapi.com/policies/privacy\""},
      {"strict-transport-security","max-age=31536000"}],
     <<"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<response xmlns=\"http://www.datapi.com/api/\" status=\""...>>}}
```

but in output file (P2 param) I see this

```
{ok,{{"HTTP/1.1",200,"OK"},
     [{"connection","keep-alive"},
      {"date","Tue, 05 May 2015 10:58:53 GMT"},
      {"server","nginx"},
      {"vary","Accept-Encoding"},
      {"content-length","5508"},
      {"content-type","application/xml; charset=utf-8"},
      {"x-frame-options","SAMEORIGIN"},
      {"p3p",
       "CP=\"To see our privacy policy, go here: http://www.datapi.com/policies/privacy\""},
      {"strict-transport-security","max-age=31536000"}],
     <<60,63,120,109,108,32,118,101,114,115,105,111,110,61,34,49,46,48,34,32,
       101,110,99,111,100,105,110,103,61,34,117,116,102,45,56,34,63,62,10,60,
       114,101,115,112,111,110,115,101,32,120,109,108,110,115,61,34,104,116,
       116,112,58,47 ... MORE NUMBERS HERE ....101,62,10>>}}.
```

That's strange, I remember that in fully interactive mode I had no problems like this. Any suggestion?

---

UPD: That's very interesting, but problem occurring only when received XML contains non-ASCII(non-Latin?) characters. In other cases, all XML in file is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the runtime is unsure whether your terminal can display non-ASCII unicode. All strings are just lists of integers, and all binaries are just long strings of bits split into bytes of 8-bits. So the numbers you are seeing *is* the data you want to see, just the raw form of it.

To display it the way you want try using a display function like `io:format/2` with a `~tp` substitution instead of a `~p` one. In your case, writing to a file, you may need to do:

```
write(Filename, UTF8_data) ->
    file:write_file(Filename, unicode:characters_to_binary(UTF8_data, utf8)).

read(Filename) ->
    case file:read_file(Filename) of
        {ok, Data} -> {ok, unicode:characters_to_list(Data, utf8)};
        Other      -> Other
    end.
```

See [Using Unicode in Erlang](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/unicode_usage.html) in the docs. Its better than it used to be, but still a bit annoying (so wrap it in some functions like the read/1 and write/2 above).

That said... Windows has its own unique form of silliness when it comes to unicode (and encodings in general), most of my Erlang experience is on Linux and BSD -- the only stuff I do on Windows is client GUI things in Wx.

Comment: Tried `~tp`. Doesn't helps. 
Tried custom read and write methods. Program stucks with no messages.

Comment: @ArmanHayots Format as a string instead of as a binary if you want to read unicode values. The `~tp` format writes an Erlang *term* in its native form, while a `~ts` will treat the argument as an IOList (which can be a binary, a list, or a deep list of any combination) and output a readable string. The read/write functions above are assuming an IOList. Either treat all your binaries as bits, and don't worry about reading them with your eyes (rather with the user-facing code), or treat them all as strings (lists) so you can read them. This is in the unicode doc linked above.